# Dataframe transform by each hour

Tags: pandas, datetime, reshape

I have a dataframe nf as follows :

```
StationID   DateTime    Channel Count
0   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 1   212
1   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 2   157
2   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 3   258
3   1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 4   158
4   1   2017-10-01 01:00:00 1   154
5   1   2017-10-01 01:00:00 2   141
6   1   2017-10-01 01:00:00 3   213
7   1   2017-10-01 01:00:00 4   132
8   1   2017-10-01 02:00:00 1   153
9   1   2017-10-01 02:00:00 2   135
10  1   2017-10-01 02:00:00 3   187
11  1   2017-10-01 02:00:00 4   127
12  1   2017-10-01 03:00:00 1   199
13  1   2017-10-01 03:00:00 2   87
14  1   2017-10-01 03:00:00 3   129
15  1   2017-10-01 03:00:00 4   92
16  1   2017-10-01 04:00:00 1   59
```

I want to transform the dataframe by each hour basis on columnwise

```
StationID   Date    Channel   Hour1 Hour2 ....... Hour24
1           2017-10-01  1     212    154 ...........
1           2017-10-01  2     157    141 ...........
```

and so on

Answer (score 2):

Notice you have hour 0 , by using `unstack`

```
df['Hour']=df.DateTime.dt.hour

df['Date']=df.DateTime.dt.date
df.set_index(['Date','StationID','Channel','Hour'])['Count'].unstack().reset_index()
Out[110]: 
Hour       Date  StationID  Channel      0      1      2      3     4
0    2017-10-01          1        1  212.0  154.0  153.0  199.0  59.0
1    2017-10-01          1        2  157.0  141.0  135.0   87.0   NaN
2    2017-10-01          1        3  258.0  213.0  187.0  129.0   NaN
3    2017-10-01          1        4  158.0  132.0  127.0   92.0   NaN
```

---

Or with `prefix` of `Hour`

```
date = df.DateTime.dt.date.rename('Date')
hour = df.DateTime.dt.hour.rename(None)

index = ['StationID', date, 'Channel']
columns = hour

pd.pivot_table(df, 'Count', index, columns).add_prefix('Hour').reset_index()

   StationID        Date  Channel  Hour0  Hour1  Hour2  Hour3  Hour4
0          1  2017-10-01        1  212.0  154.0  153.0  199.0   59.0
1          1  2017-10-01        2  157.0  141.0  135.0   87.0    NaN
2          1  2017-10-01        3  258.0  213.0  187.0  129.0    NaN
3          1  2017-10-01        4  158.0  132.0  127.0   92.0    NaN
```

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but this is not the output I require. I would need  Date also as a column. Besides, the code provided by you gives an error as there is no variable as Hour. Please refer to the output I would need . THanks for the help

Comment: I need Columns StationId, Date, Channel, Hour0.....Hour23. and the corresponding values for the same

Comment: @Wen sorry for the intrusion.  Easier than a comment

Comment: @piRSquared that is great modify Sir : -)